# Eclipse RCP local history is empty

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to get the local history for a file, but its always empty:

```java
FileSystemResourceManager fsm =
                ((org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace)ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()).getFileSystemManager();
                IFileState[] fileStates =
                fsm.getHistoryStore().getStates(myFile.getFullPath(),null);
```

In the **.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/** folder I can find the items for the file, but I cant reach them via code.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs you are using are internal use only and are not part of the Eclipse API, see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html).

You get the `IFileState` from an `IFile` object using the `getHistory` method.

```java
IFile file = get ifile

IFileState [] states = file.getHistory(progress monitor);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason this can be also empty?

Comment: Do you mean you get an empty array? The history is only recorded if the code calling `IFile.setContents` requests it.

Comment: Yes. I see that there is a KEEP_HISTORY flag in use but I cant specify it to each file. However the aforementioned folder has the file's history, I just cant reach it.

Comment: How are you getting the `IFile`?

Comment: The IFile is part of our model. Basically we have a custom editor and navigator using a custom model class. It has a property with the File. The file exists because both our editor and text editor can open it. I cant get any errors but I see that the history files are getting saved. The file is created manually with IFile.create

Comment: Does right clicking on the file and selecting `Replace With > Local History` show the history?

Comment: We dont have that menu because we hide every basic eclipse menu to show our owns. Unfortunately I dont know how to put that one back. Our navigator shows our model, not files, so I'd suspect selections dont work like in a regular navigator either.